# $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}))^n$

Tags: limits, exponentiation

How would you find this limit ?

> $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}))^n$

Thank you.

Comment: It seems a homework question, isn't it? So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I actually came across this question while studying a problem, but it is not really a question in the homework.

Comment: Note that we can *see* what the answer should be. By the power series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$, we have $1+\ln(1-1/(2n))=1-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2)$. Now use $(1+t/n)^n\approx e^t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(1+\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}))^n =
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left((1+\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}))^{\frac1{\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n})}}\right)^{n\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n})}=
e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}) }$$
provided the limit in the exponent exists. (Since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left((1+\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}))^{\frac1{\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n})}}\right) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{\frac1x}=e$.)

So it only remains to compute the limit from the exponent. We get
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}) =
-\frac12 \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n})}{-\frac1{2n}}=-\frac12$$ 
using $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$.

So the original limit is $e^{-1/2}$.

---

A similar basic idea can be used in many computations of this type -- to rewrite this as limits containing expression $\left(1+\frac1{f(n)}\right)^{f(n)}$ where $f(n)\to\infty$ or $(1+g(n))^{\frac1{g(n)}}$ where $g(n)\to0$ and the compute the new limit in the exponent.

---

You can also use wolframalpha and click there on "show steps":

[limit n to infty (1+ln(1-1/(2n)))^n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+to+infty+%281%2Bln%281-1%2F%282n%29%29%29%5En)

Answer (score 2):

If there is any limit of the form $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\left ( 1+f\left ( x \right ) \right )^{\frac{1}{g\left ( x \right )}}$$such that$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f\left ( x \right )=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g\left ( x \right )=0$$ It is given by $$e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{f\left ( x \right )}{g\left ( x \right )}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the limit of the logarithm:

$$
\eqalign{
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } \ln [ 1+\ln (1-{1\over 2n})]^n
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }{\ln [ 1+\ln (1-{1\over 2n})]\over 1/n}\cr
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }{{1\over [ 1+\ln (1-{1\over 2n})]}\cdot{1\over 1-{1\over2n}}\cdot 
{1\over2n^2}\over -1/n^2}\cr
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }{{1\over [ 1+\ln (1-{1\over 2n})]}\cdot{1\over 1-{1\over 2n}}\cdot 
{-1\over2 } }\cr
&=-1/2.
}
$$
So the original limit is $e^{-1/2}$.